# Display popular post in one week not working

Tags: wordpress

I am still struggling with some codes...please help? I have this

```
<?php
query_posts('meta_key=post_views_count&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC&posts_per_page=2');
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php
endwhile; endif;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

The code above gets popular post of all time but I just want to limit it to popular post in a week. Thanks

Comment: Add a date_query parameter to your query. This documentation page has clear examples: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters

Comment: ok... I tried looking into that but was able to find this ```$popular_post_args = array(

 'meta_key'  => 'post_views_count', //meta key currently set
 'cat'       => '265',
 'post_type' => 'post',
 'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num', //orderby currently set
 'order'      => 'DESC', //order currently set
 'posts_per_page' => 1, // show 2 posts
 'date_query' => array( // date query from after 1 week ago
  array(
   'after' => '1 week ago',
  ),
 ),
); ``` but it only works when the category ID is 1 to 100. Anything from 100 as your category ID will not display. For instance 265

Comment: Check out how this guy did it: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/120693

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this.

```
 $today = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');

 $one_week_ago = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today . ' - 7 days'));

 $args = array(


         'date_query' => array(

            array(
            'before' => $today,
            'after' => $one_week_ago,
            'inclusive' => true
            ),
          ),

         'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
         'orderby' => 'meta_val_num',
         'order' => 'DESC',
         'posts_per_page' => 2

       );

$query = new WP_Query($args);


if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();  ?>

    <li><a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

<?php

endwhile; 
endif;
```

Comment: seems that its working but the ordering doesnt seem to apply the sorting as integer correctly